# How to store the favicon.ico of any url in a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript

Ok I know how to fetch and display the favicon of any url....by this:

```
icon[x].setAttribute("src","http://"+ curl + "/favicon.ico")
```

> "curl" is the domain part of a particular url

But before setting up the favicon for any url, I want to check whether it has actually fetched any favicon. Because for some sites no favicon is fetched, and no icon is shown for that Url on my page. So basically i want to first fetch the favicon in a variable and check whether there is any icon in the variable. If not, it would put a default image. 
I just wish to know how can i fetch a favicon to get stored in a variable and then check if there is any image present.

[This is my code...Please check it once](http://jsfiddle.net/rk258yhy/)

Comment: You could add en event listener for the `error` event on that image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I'm not 100% sure, if I understand your problem correctly.

```
var icon = '';
for(var a = 0; a < document.getElementsByTagName('link').length;a++) { 
 if(document.getElementsByTagName('link')[a].getAttribute('rel') == 'shortcut icon') {
  // favicon found
  icon = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[a].getAttribute('href');
 }
}
// if no favicon is found, 'icon' is an empty string
// and a new DOM element ("link") needs to be added to show the icon
if(icon == '') {
 var node = document.createElement("LINK"); 
 node.setAttribure('rel', 'shortcut icon');
 node.setAttribute('href','http://link.to/favicon.ico');
 document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
}
```

Comment: There's no jQuery tag